# Power BI Allows Only one Filtering Path Between Tables in a Data Model

Tags: filtering, limit, powerbi

I am trying to add relationships for multiple tables but Power Bi is only allowing ONE table to be with "Both" for the "Cross Filter Direction".

If I try to select other tables to be with "Both" cross filter, then an error comes up saying "Power BI Desktop allows only one filtering path between tables in a Data Model". Is there a way to go around that?

I have three data sets ( tables ), that are joined based on two non-unique columns. First dataset (table) has site, item numbers, orders, due dates. Second dataset (table) has site, item numbers, and available quantities. Third dataset has site, item numbers, and released orders to manufacture. The three non-unique columns are sites and item numbers.

Out of these three datasets (tables), I have created two more datasets with one unique columns (sites, and item numbers) to inforce unique relationships between the three datasets.

The problem that I am facing is when I have filtering in the models it doesn't flow back and forth between the datasets. I assume fixing the filtering direction will result in fixing that.

[image]

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more concrete with your description? What do your tables look like and what are you joining on? What is it that you need to flow across tables?

Comment: Modified my initial post, please let me know if that helps. The error that I get is that “Power BI allows only one filtering path between tables in a Data Model. Deactivate existing relationships between the tables or change their filter direction. This relationship can be added as one-way filtering”.

Comment: Posting the relationship diagram would be useful as well.

Comment: I think when you wrote "dataset" above you meant "table"? In Power BI terms, a dataset is a collection of tables, stored in one PBIX file.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I posted the relationship diagram

Comment: @MikeHoney Yes I mean tables. I modified that in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the **Both** cross filter direction for that scenario.  As you are observing it comes with a lot of restrictions, so I only use it for "Many-to-Many" scenarios - not what you described.

I think you are on the right path with your **sites** and **item number** tables.  Just be careful to use the copy of the fields in those tables (e.g. **item number** from **item numbers**) in your visuals, not the same fields in the 3 "data" tables.

Comment: That's a good point, and yes I made sure that the item numbers are related by APPENDING all distinct items from the "Due" and "Available" Tables, and make it a new table "Item Numbers".

Comment: Any idea now why this error comes up ? Is there a way to go around it ?

Comment: “Power BI allows only one filtering path between tables in a Data Model. Deactivate existing relationships between the tables or change their filter direction. This relationship can be added as one-way filtering”. Is there anything we can do to go around this Power BI Limitation ?

Comment: Sure - just follow the steps in my answer.